# Upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 causes "binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named ..." error

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, .net-4.5.2

I've upgraded my ASP.NET MVC web application from .Net 4.5 to 4.5.2. After doing this I started getting a compiler error stating:

`The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'FranchiseDirectoryMigrationEndpoint'. This is an invalid value for binding Configuration`

This is referring to a second endpoint for the StoreConfigurationService. But strangely, it's listing the error as being in Reference.svcmap for each of the *other* service references in the project (E.G. The QueueService's Reference.svcmap), and not the StoreConfigurationService.

I tried updating the service reference (using the VS 2013 solution explorer) and got the same error in a popup dialog. I ended up deleting the service reference and recreating it to see if that would fix it. It can now update the service reference without the error, but I still get it when I try to build the project.

Here is what it generated in my web app's web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StoreConfigurationEndpoint" />
    <binding name="FranchiseDirectoryMigrationEndpoint" />

    <binding name="DefaultSecuredEndpoint" ...>...</binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3476/StoreConfigurationService/StoreConfigurationService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StoreConfigurationEndpoint"
    contract="StoreConfigService.IStoreConfigurationService" name="StoreConfigurationEndpoint1" />
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3476/StoreConfigurationService/StoreConfigurationService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FranchiseDirectoryMigrationEndpoint"
    contract="StoreConfigService.IFranchiseDirectoryMigrator" name="FranchiseDirectoryMigrationEndpoint" />

  <endpoint address="http://localhost:3476/QueueService/QueueService.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultSecuredEndpoint"
    contract="QueueService.IQueueService" name="QueueEndpoint1" />
</client>
```

Here is the server-side service endpoint configuration:

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServices.StoreConfigurationServiceBehavior" name="WebServices.StoreConfigurationService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="StoreConfigurationEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WebServices.IStoreConfigurationService" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="FranchiseDirectoryMigrationEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WebServices.IFranchiseDirectoryMigrator" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <service behaviorConfiguration="WebServices.QueueServiceBehavior" name="WebServices.QueueService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="QueueEndpoint" bindingName="" contract="WebServices.IQueueService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="QueueMetadataEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

I have no idea what it's talking about. It almost sounds like it thinks every service reference is supposed to have a "FranchiseDirectoryMigrationEndpoint".

Comment: I got rid of the error by updating each of the other service references that it was complaining about the Reference.svcmap for. When I compare the files to the previous versions, all I see are differences in ordering of the generated code and some additional data contract stuff. I don't know what it thought the problem was.